# ¿Se pueden llamar igual un atributo en una clase estatica y el nombre de un parametro?

Tags: c#

Intento realizar lo siguiente;

```
     class StringRotation
        {
           private static char[] Primera = new char[256];
           private static char[] segunda = new char[256];
           public static int ShiftedDiff(string primera, string segunda)
             {
                 Primera = primera.ToCharArray();
                 segunda = segunda.ToCharArray();
                 return 0;
        }
```

La variable **"segunda"** se llama igual que el parámetro del metodo **"ShiftedDiff"**, por lo tanto, el compilador interpreta que en la linea **"segunda = segunda.ToCharArray();"** es toy haciendo referencia a la misma variable.
Me gustaría utilizar el **"this."**, como si de una clase dinámica se tratase pero no es posible, ¿En estos casos que reglas de estilo se utilizan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supongo que la forma sería la siguiente:

```
class StringRotation
    {
       private static char[] Primera = new char[256];
       private static char[] segunda = new char[256];
       public static int ShiftedDiff(string primera, string segunda)
         {
             StringRotation.Primera = primera.ToCharArray();
             StringRotation.segunda = segunda.ToCharArray();
             return 0;
    }
```

Prueba y ya comentas si te funcionó.

Comment: A parte de ser la solución al problema que comenta Edulon es recomendable siempre prefijar las variables con el modificador correspondiente para facilitar la lectura, así no tienes dudas de si una variables es un parametro, un atributo de la clase, un atributo estático, etc ...